# Fusion Tables API advanced visualizations

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

From the [google](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/adv_fusiontables) example; i want to  replace the column bar chart with a dynamic pie chart. How do i do that. What codes do I need to change?

Comment: chartType: "ColumnChart" change to  chartType: "PieChart"

Comment: What about a 3D pie chart?

Comment: If you set the is3D option to true, your pie chart will be drawn as though it has three dimensions: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#3D